# Widget not expanded

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have problem with my flutter.
I create list with each item display index and some information. the problem is my information is not take the size available by the row. you can see in the picture:

[image: text is not expanded, I hope text is expanding and take the size.]

Here my code:

```
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => _showDetailDialog(activityLog),
          splashColor: Colors.grey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            '${(startItem + index) + 1}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text('oapejfajemflkjapofjaowfnpawjf[ajpfjawpkfpoawkfpoawpfainefo;iajfoiawjpfjawpjfpamefpjapiefjaiopwjfepoawjpfojeawopfjwaop'),
//                      child:
//                    _createTitle(activityLog),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                thickness: 2,
                color: Colors.grey,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `crossAxisAlignment` value equal to `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` for your `Column` widget along with `mainAxisAlignment`.